# problems with CSS3 transform and transition

Tags: javascript, css

user clicks menu option:

- current contents of div swirl, get small and disappear

  those contents are replaced with other contents via replaceChild

  the new contents start small, swirl and show

if the old and new contents are the same, it works fine; but if different, the swirl down works but the new contents simply appear full size after 500ms

when it works, the effect is quite nice

here's a complete working example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var d1 = document.createElement('div');
d1.className = 't';
d1.innerHTML = 'testing1';
var d2 = document.createElement('div');
d2.className = 't';
d2.innerHTML = 'testing2';
function test(no) { 
    // current
    var cur_dom = document.body.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    cur_dom.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(180deg) scale(0.1)";
    setTimeout( step2, 500 );
    // new
    function step2() {
            // replace node with part
            var new_dom = (no==1) ? d1 : d2;
            cur_dom.parentNode.replaceChild(new_dom,cur_dom);
            new_dom.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(0deg)";
    }
    return false;
};
</script>
<style>
div     { border: 1px solid red; }
div.t   { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) scale(0.1);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-in-out 500ms; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href='#' onclick='return test(1)'>test1</a>
<a href='#' onclick='return test(2)'>test2</a>
<div class='t'>this will be replaced</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your problem is a bit difficult to grasp. Can you provide a working sample?

Comment: @RoToRa - now have complete working example as single html file

Answer (score 1):

took the coward's way out and, instead of dom assignment, copied the innerHTML of the new dom to the existent dom, and rotated it

```
cur_dom.innerHTML = new_dom.innerHTML;
cur_dom.style.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(0deg)";
```

works just fine.  but still ugly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the new element you put in place isn't rotated. You basically solved the problem, and it's not ugly, but the correct thing to do. You can also leave out the generation of the "replacement" DIVs and just change the content of the original one:

```
        cur_dom.innerHTML = (no==1) ? 'testing1' : 'testing2';
        cur_dom.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(0deg)";
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CTxVu/

Comment: I think you're right.  I can do the replacement, but I need to do it one level lower than the actual div getting rotated.